# MobX autorun and reaction inside constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, autorun

Do **autorun** and **reaction** have to be inside the *constructor* in order to work?
Can I write this simple example without *constructor*?

Also the code that I have inside the **autorun** runs normally but if I change it to `console.log(this.expenses)` it doesn't work. Why is that?

```
import { observable, action, computed, useStrict, autorun, reaction } from 'mobx'
useStrict(true)

class ExpensesStore {

  @observable.shallow expenses = []

  @action addExpense = (expense) => {
   this.expenses.push(expense)
  }

  @computed get getExpense() {
    if(this.expenses.length > 0) {
      return `This is computed from ${this.expenses[0] + this.expenses[1]}`
    }

  }


  constructor() {
    autorun(() => {
      console.log(`${this.expenses}`)
    })

    reaction(
      ()=>this.expenses.map(expense => expense), expense => console.log(expense)
    )
  }


}

const store = window.store= new ExpensesStore()

export default store
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**autorun** and **reaction** does not have to be in the constructor. You could for example do this if you prefer:

**Example**

```
class ExpensesStore {
  @observable.shallow expenses = []

  @action addExpense = (expense) => {
   this.expenses.push(expense)
  }

  @computed get getExpense() {
    if(this.expenses.length > 0) {
      return `This is computed from ${this.expenses[0] + this.expenses[1]}`
    }
  }
}

const store = new ExpensesStore()

autorun(() => {
  console.log(`${store.expenses}`)
})

reaction(
  () => store.expenses.map(expense => expense), expense => console.log(expense)
)
```

The reason why `` console.log(`${this.expenses}`) `` works and `console.log(this.expenses)` doesn't is because you are not dereferencing anything in your shallow array when you write `this.expenses`.

When you write...

```
`${this.expenses}`
```

... you are implicitly calling `toString()` on `this.expenses`. You can use [**toJS**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/tojson.html) or `slice` to get the same effect when not putting it in a string:

**Example ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ririzugeya/1/edit?js,console))**

```
class ExpensesStore {
  @observable.shallow expenses = []

  @action addExpense = (expense) => {
   this.expenses.push(expense)
  }

  @computed get getExpense() {
    if(this.expenses.length > 0) {
      return `This is computed from ${this.expenses[0] + this.expenses[1]}`
    }
  }
}

const store = new ExpensesStore()

autorun(() => {
  // store.expenses.slice() works just as well
  console.log(toJS(store.expenses))
})

reaction(
  () => store.expenses.map(expense => expense), expense => console.log(expense)
)

setTimeout(() => {
  store.addExpense(1000)
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Thx Tholle. I see  my mistake considering console.log. 
So if autorun and reaction don't need any decorators and can live outside class ExpensesStore, I can take them out, put them in some other component and run them from there. Is there a way to take actions and computed outide to. I would like to make a structure similar to redux where I woul have actions in one file, store in another?

Comment: @Igor-Vuk No problem! Absolutely, MobX is very flexible. I would personally keep the computeds on the classes in that case, but move the actions. I did that myself in a project not long ago, and it felt like a nice, mutable version of Redux.

Comment: How would I do that, taking out the actions and dispatching them from another file? I made another question if you want to join in. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46840028/structure-mobx-project-like-redux
I will accept this answer as a solution to my first question. Thx.

Comment: @Tholle what if the new instance is being instantiated in a separate place, say in a root store? Where would you put the autorun?