# Structure Mobx project like Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I would like to structure mobx project to look like redux project. Store configuration in one file, actions in another file, maybe some other logic and reactions in third file.

Also, what is the best practice? To have one store like redux or more. How would I do that (taking out @action from inside a class and dispatching it from another file). Can anybody give some nice examples of structuring their projects?

Answer (score 0):

Decorators (`@`) are a nice way to use MobX with classes, but you can use MobX without using them at all.

You could structure your application like this, by using the function version of `action`:

**Example ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/volezanoce/edit?js,console)**)

```
// state.js
useStrict(true);

const appState = observable({
  count: 0,
  firstName: 'Igor',
  lastName: 'Vuk',
  fullName: computed(function() {
    return `${this.firstName}-${this.lastName}`;
  })
});

// actions.js
const increment = action(function() {
  ++appState.count;
});

const changeLastName = action(function() {
  appState.lastName = 'Stravinskij';
});

// app.js
autorun(() => {
  console.log(`${appState.fullName} has been logged in for ${appState.count} seconds`);
});

setInterval(() => {
  increment();
}, 1000);

setTimeout(() => {
  changeLastName();
}, 3000)
```

Comment: Thanks Tholle. This is pretty nice. So does that mean that I can not do the same(separate actions, computed...) while using the @ decorators?

Comment: You could put your actions (increment and changeLastName in this example) in a separate `class Actions` and use decorators, and create one instance of it `const actions = new Actions();` if your would prefer.

Comment: Thanks Tholle. I did it. It works pretty nice. What is your suggestion? How would you structure it. Putting actions in separate file/class and leaving computed in a class together with observable? What about reactions and other logic?

Comment: @Igor-Vuk Great! Computeds are basically cached computations, and as long as all the observables the computed relies on are on the same class, I think it makes sense to have the computed on the class as well. I like putting autoruns and reactions in the React components, but it depends on what you want to use the reactions for. `componentDidMount() { this.disposer = autorun(() => ... ); }`, `componentWillUnmount() { this.disposer(); }`

Comment: Ou, that is interesting. So you are putting your autorun and reactions inside componentDidMount lifecycle method and disposing of them in componentWillUnmount. I just tried it, it works pretty nice. There aren't many project examples on internet so gems like this are welcomed.